# Ubuntu 16.04 : Unable to connect to wifi after kernel update (4.4.0-116-generic)

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless, kernel, broadcom

I'm having an issue with my wireless after upgrading the kernel from 112 to 116. I have tried reinstalling bcmwl-kernel-source and updating gcc to 5.4.1 but to no avail. Even booting back to 112 I have lost wireless (which had worked previously to me reinstalling bcmwl-kernel-source)

It seems as though the reinstallation of bcmwl-kernel-source is working well until the modprobe stage where I get this error:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Exec format error
```

I can replicate this by the command:

```
sudo modprobe wl
```

I believe there is a problem with the wl module, and a grep for wl in dmesg shows:

```
wl: version magic '4.4.0-116-generic SMP mod_unload modversions ' should be '4.4.0-116-generic SMP mod_unload modversions retpoline '
```

I am fairly new to ubuntu and am not sure how to fix this so I could definitely use some help.

here is the output of lshw -C network

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not 
upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,544 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 396824 files and directories currently 
installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom- 
0ubuntu1~1.2_amd64.deb ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
rmdir: failed to remove '': No such file or directory
Done.
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.2) over 
(6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.2) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.2) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom DKMS files...
Building only for 4.4.0-116-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.4.0-116-generic
Done.

wl:
Running module version sanity check.

Good news! Module version  for wl.ko
exactly matches what is already found in kernel 4.4.0-116-generic.
DKMS will not replace this module.
You may override by specifying --force.

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Exec format error
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.11) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-116-generic
```

here is the modinfo:

```
modinfo wl | grep vermagic

vermagic:       4.4.0-116-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
```

Comment: Please edit to add results for `modinfo wl | grep vermagic`

Comment: Edited to show the modinfo. Let me know if there's anything else too that could be useful to debug

Comment: Can you `sudo modprobe -fv wl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a temporary working internet connection by ethernet, tethered or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Reboot and let us know the result.

Comment: Hey chili555, I've tried this many times with no luck

Comment: Please try the steps here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2386370

Comment: Tried the steps but I cannot run a reinstallation of bcmwl-kernel-source on kernel 109 because I cannot even connect through ethernet on it. The wireless is gone as well there

Comment: Isn't -109 or some other earlier kernel available at the GRUB menu?

Comment: I had -109 and -112 at the GRUB menu. Looks like running the reinstall at -112 fixed the wireless problem. Thank you very much! I wonder what happened in -116...

Comment: I'm still hoping for a solution for -116 but for the time being, stick on -112.